# Json Web Token vs WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2012, jwt

I'm actually struggling to implement JWT (Json Web Token) in my WCF project. I've end-up to think that WCF did not support JWT.

Am I right? Am I Wrong?

Thanks!

I'm working on C# on Visual Studio 2012

**Edit:**
My Problem:
When I try to implement it in my WCF project, I'm getting an error telling me that the JwtSecurityTokenHandler class isn't recognize due to missing Interface ISecurityTokenValidator. This interface suppose to be included in System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.dll. but I can't find it in that assembly. I'm missing something here and can't find what.

Here's my class that gives me some trouble.
This is part of a WCF project started from scratch, I just added the TokenManager Class, and reference to JWT nuget reference as stated in the package.config

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace POC_JWT_Service.Security
{
    public class TokenManager
    {
        public object GetToken()
        {
            var plainTextSecurityKey = "This is my shared, not so secret, secret!";
            var signingKey = new InMemorySymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainTextSecurityKey));

            var signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(signingKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature, SecurityAlgorithms.Sha256Digest);


            var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim>()
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "myemail@myprovider.com"),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Administrator"),
            }, "Custom");

            var securityTokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor()
            {
                AppliesToAddress = "http://my.website.com",
                TokenIssuerName = "http://my.tokenissuer.com",
                Subject = claimsIdentity,
                SigningCredentials = signingCredentials,
            };


            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var plainToken = tokenHandler.CreateToken(securityTokenDescriptor);
            var signedAndEncodedToken = tokenHandler.WriteToken(plainToken);

            Console.WriteLine("plainToken.ToString()");
            Console.WriteLine(plainToken.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }
    }
}
```

packages.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net452" requireReinstallation="True" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="9.0.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" version="4.0.2.206221351" targetFramework="net452" />

</packages>
```

Comment: The beauty of JWT is the simplicity and the ability to use without special libraries. Of course, using a library is much easier, but WCF doesn't support it or not support it. Your code does or doesn't.

Comment: Ok so you mean WCF do not have something to do in this? but when I try to implement it in my WCF project, I'm getting an error telling me that the JwtSecurityTokenHandler class isn't recognize due to missing Interface  ISecurityTokenValidator. This interface suppose to be included in System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.dll. but I can't find it in that assembly. I'm missing something here and can't find what.

Comment: [it is on nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt/)

Comment: It's the nuget package that give me this trouble

Comment: I could share my proof of concept project if you wish.

Comment: If you can post a minimal but complete example I'll take a look but in my experience there is nothing minimal about WCF. Are you implementing a custom binding? Or implementing a message listener?

Comment: I've edited the main topic to add some code. Thanks for your time

Comment: You also have to explain the problem.

Comment: Main post edited to include problem

Comment: There seems to be ambiguity between System.IdentityModel.Tokens and Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens. Sorry, I don't know which you want, or which is right. But it has nothing specifically to do with WCF.

Comment: The original question was, is JwT should work with WCF, and the answer, is: "Yes" so at that point I'll continue to search other way to implement it.